# Android Layout with Scrollview not at bottom - Fragment

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

What am I doing wrong that I can't get my "toolbar" to show up at the bottom of the screen (the free and post buttons)?  I'm having to wrap this all inside a scroll view so that the keyboard will shift the view when displayed.

=======
UPDATE:  Sorry I should have stated that the FREE and POST buttons must be at the bottom of the screen and maintain their size.

This is a FRAGMENT and the mainActivity has been set to android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan" however keyboard display is not scrolling the either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".CreateFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/red">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/puregreen"
                android:id="@+id/createTopView"
                android:clickable="false">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/createRecylerView" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:hint="Title"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:id="@+id/createTitleTextView"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/createRecylerView"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:hint="Description"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:id="@+id/createDescriptionTextView"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/createTitleTextView"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="+ Tags"
                        android:id="@+id/createTagsTextView"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/createBottomToolbar"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:id="@+id/createBottomToolbar"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="FREE"
                                android:background="@drawable/button_rounded"
                                android:id="@+id/createCoinButton"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="POST"
                                android:id="@+id/createPostButton"
                                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:background="@color/my_blue" />

                    </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: Must the FREE and POST buttons appear at the bottom of the screen after finishing scrolling, or they must always be at the bottom no matter the current scroll position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have changed some code please try this code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/createTopView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/createRecylerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/createRecylerView">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/createTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/createRecylerView"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/createDescriptionTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/createTitleTextView"
            android:hint="Description"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/createTagsTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/createBottomToolbar"
            android:text="+ Tags"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/createBottomToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/createCoinButton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="FREE" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/createPostButton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="POST"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks for the try,  http://prntscr.com/bm3rzk however when I tried that I loose the other controls and the fee / post buttons are 50% of the row when they have to maintain their size as originally posted.  Also the Free/Post have to be at the bottom of the screen, and the +Tags needs to be just above that.

Comment: have you set adapter with data?

Comment: yep.  Has a single element in it.  Will also need it to move up when the keyboard is shown as well which it is not

Comment: just put this property in recycler view app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Answer (score 1):

Your toolbar is wrapped in a RelativeLayout which is wrapped in another RelativeLayout of which layout_height is set to wrap_content, here it is:

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/red">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!-- here -->
    android:background="@color/puregreen"
    android:id="@+id/createTopView"
    android:clickable="false">
```

Try changing this to match_parent and see if it works.

Comment: Tried that.. same results

Comment: This worked after moving it inside of a scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `linearLayout` as the child of `scrollView`? And set `fillViewport` property of the `scrollView` to true to stretch it's contents. Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".CreateFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="@color/red">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/createTopView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/puregreen">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/createRecylerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/createTitleTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Title"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/createDescriptionTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Description"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/createTagsTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+ Tags"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/createBottomToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/createCoinButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_rounded"
                    android:text="FREE"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/createPostButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@color/my_blue"
                    android:text="POST"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for the try, however the fee and post buttons still are not at the bottom of the screen and they now take up 50% of the row.  They need to remain the size they were in the image posted.  See this http://prntscr.com/bm3rjr

Comment: Edited my answer. I've added and set `fillViewport` property of the `scrollView` to `true` to adjust it's contents whenever there's an available space.